# Demographic Reporting in Universal Analytics with GTM

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Tag Manager. I need to see demographics reporting but it says I need to validate the code. GTM has already been installed on the site and the analytics tag has "Enable Display Advertising Features" checked. Should I skip validation since I am using GTM? Is there anything else I need to do to get access to demographic reporting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the validation if you believe that you have set everything up correctly. In GTM, you will need to check

```
Enable Display Advertising Features
```

for your tags. This is located right under the Tracking ID field for the tag.

Comment: I am using Google Tag Manager to deploy tags. The only code that's on the site is the GTM code. Are you saying I still need to add this line of code even if I'm using the GTM for tag management?

Comment: No, sorry, just changed my answer. :)

Comment: Cool, that's what I did. Looks like I am just hopefully waiting for the data to come in. Thank you so much!